# Tagging latest with semantic release

Tags: github, github-actions, semantic-release

So in our setup, we're using Github and Github Actions. We release to npm using semantic-release. We have a CI run that pushes to production when we release on either our main branch or our bugfix branch. However, when we push to main, the release gets tagged with latest and is thus immediately found and used by npm. Whereas whenever we push to bugfix, the release gets tagged with bugfix instead, and as such is only installed if someone knows about that version and specifically requests it.

How would I go about changing it so that when we push to bugfix it also gets tagged with latest?